# Swift MVVM: Where to keep custom model data if we have an array of models

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, architecture

I have a json response and model as below

```
[
  {
  "name":"Name 1",
  "class":"class 1",
  "school":"school 1"
  },
  {
  "name":"Name 2",
  "class":"class 2",
  "school":"school 3"
  }
]
```

And its model class as below

```
typealias StudentArray = [Student]

class Student: Codable {
    let name: String
    let section: String
    let school: String

    init(name: String, section: String, school: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.section = section
        self.school = school
    }
}
```

I want to filter the entire array based on the section and keep separate array for each section.

I also need to keep other filtered data.

Which is the best place for it? ViewModel or the Student Model class.

Comment: ViewModel would be the recommended place for me.

Comment: Business logic should be in Model and Presentation logic should be in ViewModel is suitable way I knew.

Comment: Student is an object which cannot know of an array of Students [Student], so definitely inside ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Model side.

Model is your actual data. Viewer observe the data from ViewModel which parses the data from Model.